# Git checkout issue

Tags: git

I have a very weird behavior with git. I have a file with some local changes that I like to revert to the last commit. My procedure is the following:

`git status`

On branch master

```
Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add <file>..." to update
what will be committed)   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard
changes in working directory)

         modified:   doc/pySPM Documentation.ipynb
```

then I do `git checkout -- doc/pySPM\ Documentation.ipynb`

but it's like it does not do anything because `git status` still displays the same as above.

What starts to be very strange for me is that deleting the local file and checking it out, still results in changes!?!?!

`rm doc/pySPM\ Documentation.ipynb`
`git checkout doc/pySPM\ Documentation.ipynb`
`git status`

```
Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add <file>..." to update
what will be committed)   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard
changes in working directory)

         modified:   doc/pySPM Documentation.ipynb
```

A hard reset also don't help.

Is their some git expert around to spot the issue or have a clue for a solution?

*My system is: Win64 with git v 2.17.1.windows.2 running is mingw64*

Comment: Ok, what is already weird is that anybody cloning it: `git clone https://github.com/scholi/pySPM.git`, will clone it with a change for that file! How is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found it. I actually have a filter in my .gitconfig and somehow the file was commited without the cleaning filter. Now each time it is cloned, the file is changed due to the filter.